# file manager no working

Tags: filesystems, admin, modx, modx-revolution

I have a problem. My file Manager has stopped working for some reason (in modx revo.)Database and system settings don`t touched me.
File manager is working BUT it can`t find the path to the files. I go to the optional field and choose the picture then I see this..

"none of the files nna falls under a specified filter"

I cant to download pictures over here. If I go to the menu: FILES ,I see this:

only an empty folder media

We were looking for a reason and in the end we understood that the manager couldn`t save the settings. Tools- Source files-
Filesystem  and I see what settings were not preserved

I click "to recover values by default" and see this:

http://cs619116.vk.me/v619116835/ad20/_-3SXphiDww.jpg

I click "save" but it doesn`t save anithing. Parameters are disappear.I don`t know what to do. Please, help.

the user is admin
access rights - super user

the access rights in a file system place a group of admins, but the settings are not saved

P.S. Sorry for my English, I hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

It's bit of a long shot, but try checking that all your `config.core.php` files are pointing to the right location, they should live at:

```
public_html/config.core.php
public_html/connectors/config.core.php
public_html/manager/config.core.php
```

and they should contain

```
<?php
define('MODX_CORE_PATH', '/home/[your cpanel username]/public_html/core/');
define('MODX_CONFIG_KEY', 'config');
?>
```

Comment: have checked everything OK